# Module not found error: what is Jupyter core?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I think this code

```
jupyter nbconvert --to script weather_observations.ipynb
```

should convert a Jupyter script to a Python script, but I get this error

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/jupyter", line 6, in <module>
    from jupyter_core.command import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_core'
(base) Users-MacBook-Air-2:~ user$ python weather_observations.py
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'weather_observations.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What is that Jupyter core?

Here is the where I got the ipynb

https://aaltoscicomp.github.io/python-for-scicomp/_downloads/4b858dab9366f77b3641c99adece5fd2/weather_observations.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

For the first error, you do not seem to have jupyter-core installed. But I also noticed you are on your base environment. I would suggest creating an environment, `conda create --name <env_name> python=3.8` [change env_name] to a name of your choice. Then install the necessary packages using pip, `pip install jupyter`.

For the second error, you seem to not be in the directory where the file 'weather_observations.py' is. Navigate to that directory usin `cd` then try re-running.

Comment: Thanks @Ahmad. I guess your advise is correct, even though I don't know what should I do with it. I'm using Jupyter lab so I don't think I'm going to create a new environment. Neither I think ```pip install jupyter```is necessary, as I'm using Python in Jupyter lab. I should have predefined all that!